# View a history of commands

Tags: commands, doom

While in web-mode, when I type `{{` emacs will add `}}` to the end, and when I press `SPC` it will then add another `}}` to the end with a space either side and one extra space to the right, so it looks like this `{{ |  }}}}`. Apparently there are two commands that are working together to "help" me, I want to disable one of them.

I am trying to find the source of the problem, so is there a way I can view the commands that caused this issue so I can fix it myself?

I am using Doom Emacs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to run `view-lossage` which will show you the last several keystrokes, and which commands they are bound to in the current buffer (which *might* not be the same as the commands they were bound to in the buffer which was active when they keys were typed -- only the keystrokes themselves are actually recorded).

n.b. Older Emacsen will display *only* the key sequences.

Comment: Thanks, I had come across that before, it appears to be `self-insert-command`, but I am at a loss of where to go from there. Another question might be in order then.

Comment: `electric-pair-mode` (and `electric-pair-local-mode`) are the in-built options for auto-paired parens.  I'm not sure what `web-mode` will be doing.